# How to use distincted select result values ​as where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the #1 code.

```
select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ
```

This results in 25 non-duplicate values(row).

and, I'm going to use the result of #1 to use a subquery.

So I wrote the following code.

```
select t5.SUBJECTNAME, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ
where (t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.teamname) in (select distinct t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
         inner join TBLSUBJECT T5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = T4.SUBJECTSEQ);
```

But this result returns 150 rows.

First, duplicate values ​​came out by using `in` in the where clause,

I think that there is a duplicate value again because the `distinct` clause is gone in mainquery.

I'm curious about an approach that can solve this problem.

best regards

**edit**

```
select t5.SUBJECTSEQ, t1.TEAMNAME
from tblteam t1
         inner join TBLCLASS t2 on t1.CLASSSEQ = t2.CLASSSEQ
         inner join TBLOPENCOURSE T on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = t2.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLOPENSUBJECT T3 on T.OPENCOURSESEQ = T3.OPENCOURSESEQ
         inner join TBLAVAILABLESUBJECT T4 on T4.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ = T3.AVAILABLESUBJECTSEQ
inner join (
             select distinct subjectseq, teamname from TBLSUBJECT, tblteam) t5 on T5.SUBJECTSEQ = t4.SUBJECTSEQ;
```

this code give 750 row...

Comment: When the distinct gives 4 rows in the subquery, the condition holds for all those 4 rows in the main query. Maybe you want a single GROUP BY/HAVING query.

Comment: What's wrong with just `select t5.SUBJECTNAME, t3.SUBJECTEND, t1.TEAMSEQ ..` in the outer query?

Comment: @Serg The problem is because the select distincted value is composed of a subquery and used as a condition of the where clause, and select distinct cannot be used in the main query.

Comment: @JoopEggen If I use group by, I have a problem that I cannot get the values of `t5.SUBJECTNAME`, `t3.SUBJECTEND`, and `t1.TEAMSEQ`.

Comment: Have you already tried `select distinct`  in the main query? What is the error ? If no errors what is the output and why it's wrong?

Comment: The `where`  clause seems pointless. If you remove it you should get the same 150 rows. So, you need to figure out why that has duplicates; either it's valid based on other columns that are not in the select list, in which case you can just use `distinct` as Serg said; or they should not be there, in which case you might be missing part of a join condition - we don't know the table structures or relationships though.